# Return the string that is between the first and last appearance of "bread" in the given string

Tags: java

This question is from coding bat and might have been asked before. Please review the code.

A sandwich is two pieces of bread with something in between. Return the string that is between the first and last appearance of "bread" in the given string, or return the empty string "" if there are not two pieces of bread.

```
getSandwich("breadjambread") → "jam"
getSandwich("xxbreadjambreadyy") → "jam"
getSandwich("xxbreadyy") → ""
```

**My code is**

```
public static String getSandwich(String str) {
        int ind = str.indexOf("bread");
        int laind = str.lastIndexOf("bread");
        if(!(laind == -1 ))return (str.substring(ind+5,laind)) ;
        return "";
    }
```

And I am getting

```
Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5 (line number:4)
```

for this input `getSandwich("xxbreadyy")`

Comment: Any thoughts on why?  Maybe because there is only one instance of bread?  Work through the code line by line with your input.  It should be pretty clear :)

Comment: indexOf() and lastIndexOf() will have the same result on your last sample data

Comment: for your last case ind == laind, & thats the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the following code

```
public static String getSandwich(String str) {
    int ind = str.indexOf("bread");
    int laind = str.lastIndexOf("bread");
    if((laind != -1 ) && (ind!=laind))
        return (str.substring(ind+5,laind)) ;
    return "";
}
```

I added `(ind!=laind)` to the condition which checks if the first and the last "bread" are NOT same.

See **[live demo](http://ideone.com/cNbHq6)** here.

Answer (score 1):

I sharing with you an alternative answer to this problem just using one line of code. Basically using indexOf() and lastIndexof() you can find the respective Strings after check if there are at least two slices of bread and return the substring between both slices. Good Luck!

```
public String getSandwich(String str) {
    return  str.matches("(.*bread.*){2}") ? str.substring(str.indexOf("bread")+5,str.lastIndexOf("bread")) : "";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String aregs[]) {
        String word = "xxbreadyy";
        System.out.println(get(word));
    }

    public static String get(String word) {
        int firstAccurance = getPosition(word);
        System.out.println("first = " + firstAccurance);
        if (firstAccurance != -1 && firstAccurance + 5 < word.length()) {
            String newWord = word.substring(firstAccurance + 5);
            System.out.println("newWord = " + newWord);
            int secondAccurance = getPosition(newWord);
            System.out.println("second = " + secondAccurance);
            if (secondAccurance != -1) {
                return word.substring(firstAccurance+5, secondAccurance+firstAccurance+5);
            } else
                return "";
        } else
            return "";
    }

    private static int getPosition(String word) {
        int i = word.indexOf("bread");
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails, Because substring method should not have start index argument greater than end index. In your case it is 7 & 2 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getSandwich(String str) 
{
  int l = str.length();
  int[] b;
  int count=0;
  b=new int[2];
  if (l<10) return "";
  for (int i=0;i<l-4;i++)
    {
    if (str.substring(i,i+5).equals("bread")) 
        {
        if (count==2) count=1;
        b[count]=i;
        count++;
        }    
    }
  if (count==2)
  {
  return str.substring(b[0]+5,b[1]);
  }  
  return "";
}
```

Comment: consider adding description/comments of your solution

Answer (score 0):

Gosh why so many lines

```
public String getSandwich(String str) {
    if (str.length() <= 10) return "";
    return str.substring(str.indexOf("bread")+5,str.lastIndexOf("bread"));
}
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer would help EIP with their problem.

Comment: I was not intended to help EIP (his problem is solved afaik), but to help others who browse for simple codingbat solutions like me just did. Why not     to post short examples for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getSandwich(String str) 
{
    //if we have something with the minimum amount of characters needed for "bread" + x + "bread",
    //Where x is a string that is not empty.
    if (str.length() >= 11)
    {
      String toTest = "bread";
      String ret = "";
      int counter = 0;
      int wordStart = 0;
      int wordEnd = 0;
      //Test forward for the first "bread" instance.
      for (int i = 5; i < str.length(); i++)
      {
        //If we find the first bread, we set the variable wordStart equal to the place where "bread" ends.
        if (str.substring(i-5, i).equals(toTest))
        {
          wordStart = i;
          //We then test backwards to find the last instance of "bread".
          //And, then we set variable wordEnd where bread begins
          for (int j = 5; j < str.length(); j++)
          {
            if (str.substring(str.length() - j, str.length() - j + 5).equals(toTest))
            {
              wordEnd = str.length() - j;
              break;
            }
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      //We return the substring from the wordStart to the wordEnd
      ret = str.substring(wordStart, wordEnd);
      return ret;
    }
    else
    {
      return "";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I did this without the indexOf function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer without using indexof keyword:

```
public String getSandwich(String str) {
    int beforestf = 0;
    int endstf = 0;
    String stf;
    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 5; i++) {
        if (str.substring(i, i + 5).equals("bread")) {
            endstf = i;
        }
    }
    for (int j = str.length(); j >= 5; j--) {
        if (str.substring(j-5, j).equals("bread")) {
            beforestf = j;
        }
    }
    if ((endstf>=5))stf=str.substring(beforestf,endstf);
    else stf="";

    return stf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getSandwich(String str) 
{
  String s="bread";
  //To have a string in between "bread" ideal string length should be greater than 10 i.e., BreadBread=Length(10)!!
  if(str.length()>10 && str.substring(str.indexOf(s)+5,str.lastIndexOf(s)).length()>0)
    return str.substring(str.indexOf(s)+5,str.lastIndexOf(s));    

  return "";  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another similar approach rather than using two for loops to get the index of first bread and second bread:

```
public String getSandwich(String str) {
  int bread1= str.indexOf("bread");
  int bread2= 0;
  for(int i=str.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
    if(str.charAt(i)=='d'&&str.charAt(i-1)=='a'&&str.charAt(i-2)=='e'&&str.charAt(i-3)=='r'&&str.charAt(i-4)=='b'){
      bread2 = i-4;
      if(bread1!=bread2)
        return str.substring(bread1+5,bread2);
    }
  }
    return "";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, which passes all the tests in CodingBat:

```
 public String getSandwich(String str) {
    String bread = "bread";

     int lIndex = str.indexOf(bread);
     int rIndex = str.lastIndexOf(bread);

      if(lIndex != -1 && rIndex != lIndex){
          return str.substring(lIndex + bread.length(), rIndex);
      }
      return "";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I approached this problem recursively and without the use of Java Strings built-in `indexOf` method like so:

```
public String getSandwich(String str) {
    final String BREAD = "bread";
    if(str.length() < BREAD.length() * 2){
        return "";
    }
    if(str.substring(0, BREAD.length()).equals(BREAD) && 
        str.substring(str.length() - BREAD.length()).equals(BREAD)){
        return str.substring(BREAD.length(), str.length() - BREAD.length());
    }
    if(! str.substring(0, BREAD.length()).equals(BREAD)){
        return getSandwich(str.substring(1));
    }
    return getSandwich(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getSandwich(String str) {

  int a = str.indexOf("bread");

  int b = str.lastIndexOf("bread");

  return b-a> 4 ?str.substring(a+5,b): "";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public String getSandwich(String str) {
    String g = "";
    int temp = str.indexOf("d");
    int  count=str.lastIndexOf("bread");

    if(!(str.contains("bread"))) {
        return g;
    }

    for(int i= temp+1;i<count;i++) {
        g = g + str.charAt(i);
    }
    return g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution, which passes all the tests in CodingBat:

```
public String getSandwich(String str) {
  int start1 = 0;
  int end1 = 0;
  
  int start2 = 0;
  int end2 = 0;
  String result = "";
  
  if (str.contains("bread") && str.length() >= 11) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if (str.charAt(i) == 'b' &&
          str.charAt(i+1) == 'r' &&
          str.charAt(i+2) == 'e' &&
          str.charAt(i+3) == 'a' &&
          str.charAt(i+4) == 'd') {
            start1 = i;
            end1 = i+4;
            break;
          }
    }
    
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      if (str.charAt(i) == 'd' &&
          str.charAt(i-1) == 'a' &&
          str.charAt(i-2) == 'e' &&
          str.charAt(i-3) == 'r' &&
          str.charAt(i-4) == 'b') {
            start2 = i-4;
            end2 = i;
            break;
          }
    }
    
    if (end1 < start2) {
      result = str.substring(end1 + 1, start2);
    }
    
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>

 using namespace std;

 int main(){
    
    string s;
    string match = "bread";
    cin>>s;

    int first_ind = 0;
    int last_ind = 0;
    int n = s.size();

    // first occurence with of bread with this first index 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        
        int j = 0;
        while(j+i<n and match[j] == s[j+i]){
            j++;
        }

        if(j==5){
            first_ind = i;
            break;
        }

    }


    // second occurence of bread with this second index 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        
        int j = 0;
        while(j+i<n and match[j] == s[j+i]){
            j++;
        }

        if(j==5 and i!=first_ind){
            last_ind = i;
            break;
        }
        
    }

    for (int i = first_ind+5; i < last_ind; ++i)
                cout<<s[i];
    
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to StackOverflow ! Can you elaborate a little bit on your answer ? It will be easier to grasp for a beginner !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).